# Creating SpatiaLite View in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, sqlite

Using these instructions (there are several other examples to find, all look the same and all of them seem to work)
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/sp-view.html
"Hand-writing your own Spatial VIEW"

I wanted to create a Spatialite View within Qgis. I tried it with DB-Manager and the QspatiaLite Plugin. I get the following error:

```sql
views_geometry_columns.read_only may not be NULL
```

Any suggestions, I don't really know where I could have made a mistake, as it used to be very simple to create a spatialite view.

I used the following code:

```sql
CREATE VIEW shape_2015 AS
SELECT komplex_nr_polyg as kompx_nr,
flaeche as flaeche,
polygone as polygone
FROM flaechen

INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
    (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column)
  VALUES ('shape_2015', 'polygone', 'kompx_nr', 'flaechen', 'polygone');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "read_only" table obviously needs some input, as I could not find anything in the cookbook, after some search I found this insightful discussion with mr. furieri himself:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/n8l977RL9-0

conclusion:

```
1 = TRUE = ReadOnly View (unsupported write ops)

0 = FALSE = Not ReadOnly, thus Writable View
```

So the statement should look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
    (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, read_only)
  VALUES ('shape_2015', 'polygone', 'kompx_nr', 'flaechen', 'polygone', 1);
```