# How to make a Spatialite View (with geometries) for QGIS based on two table

Tags: qgis, spatialite, spatial-view

There are several posts ([1)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/can-qgis-read-spatialite-views), [2)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176652/creating-spatialite-view-in-qgis)) and manuals to create a spatial view within a Spatialite Database and to work with it in QGIS.

The important thing is to register the view in geometry_columns table:

> ```
> INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
> (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column)
> VALUES ('italy', 'geometry', 'ROWID', 'local_councils', 'geometry');
> ```

All examples are about views which were created from one table.

How I have to register this view?

```
CREATE VIEW photo_object AS
SELECT a.id, MakeLine(b.geom, a.geom) AS geom
FROM object a, photo b
    WHERE a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try is not supported. As you can see from the structure of the **views_geometry_columns** table the **f_table_name** and **f_geometry_column** fields are referencing one single table and one single geometry column. You can't register your computed geometry `MakeLine(b.geom, a.geom)` into spatial views.

You must convert your view into a real table with CREATE TABLE AS even it means wasting some disk space. You can do that with ogr2ogr which should automatically take care of updating the metadata tables as well.

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite -update -sql "SELECT a.rowid, MakeLine(b.geometry, a.geometry) AS geometry FROM foo1 a, foo2 b WHERE a.ogc_fid=b.ogc_fid;" test.sqlite test.sqlite -nln bar -nlt linestring
```

Comment: Thank you. I see, I have to create a workaround: create table, update table with ogr2ogr, put these things in a QGIS Plugin (PyQGIS).

Comment: Try the ogr2ogr solution that I added to my answer.

Comment: Nice solution. I've had it done more cumbersome. One short question: I've to use `-overwrite` in addition to `-update` to "update" the table (otherwise `Error 1: Layer test already exists`). Doesn't take the `-update` this into account?

Comment: Yes, -update is for datasource and in this case it means that the same Spatialite database is updated - otherwise it will be overwritten. Take a backup if you want to try. For re-creating a layer use -overwrite, for adding new records use -append. Options are mostly documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question with an already accepted answer, but I found this post when searching a solution for my problem and I had a different approach to get my spatial view registered.

So, in my case, I had to reproject the original geometries into another CRS, so I also couldn't use the reference to the original geometry table to insert the attributes of the spatial view into `views_geometry_columns` table.

---

To resolve this I've created a 'dummy' table just with the sole purpose of creating a reference table with the adequate geometry type and CRS for the metadata of the spatial view I wanted to create.

1 - First I created the dummy table with the adequate geometry type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dummy_etrs_pl (
    OBJECTID integer primary key autoincrement not null,
    SHAPE MULTIPOLYGON
)
```

2 - Set the adequate metadata for the geometry column of the dummy table:

```sql
SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('dummy_etrs_pl','shape',3763,'MULTIPOLYGON',2)
```

3 - Inserted the metadata for the spatial view into `views_geometry_columns` table referencing the dummy table for the *f_table_name* and *f_geometry_column* attributes:

```sql
INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
(view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, read_only)
VALUES ('etrs_freg_pl', 'shape', 'objectid', 'dummy_etrs_pl', 'shape', 1)
```

The resulting spatial view was correctly recognized in SpatialLite_GUI and QGIS.

---

As the dummy table is set with no spatial index, the spatial view is recognized as having no spatial index as well, which is good, since the spatial index would have no correspondence with the existing geometries in the spatial view.

This approach has advantages aggainst the solution of creating a real table with the results of the query:

1. avoids creating "duplicated" data in the database
2. assures that the data in the resulting layer is up-to-date (as it is an actual view of the input tables)
3. the dummy table can be used as a referenced to several spatial views, if they have the same geometry type and SRID